# Change the name log names with increment number when new log name created

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have following log files in my directory

> process.1.log, process.2.log, process.3.log, process.4.log, process.5.log

I want to run one script or command where the directory files should change

> process.2.log, process.3.log, process.4.log, process.5.log, process.6.log

Comment: Does it mean that you want to rename the files? Renaming is done by the `mv` command. Of course you will start with renaming the highest number first (process.5.log), to avoid logfiles to be overwritten. Use the `-i` option of `mv` to protect yourself from this kind of error.

Comment: Please be more specific, like which OS you are working upon.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [`rename`](https://linuxize.com/post/rename-command-in-linux/) rather than `mv`. Of course we *will start with renaming the highest number first* as user1934428 wrote, but `rename` without any extra option prevents loss of logfiles if we get the order wrong.

```
ls -rv process.*.log|rename 's/\d+/$&+1/e'
```

Comment: [Why not to parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) The is a problem with rename is that there is [util-linux rename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) and [perl rename](https://www.linux.pl/man/index.php?command=rename). I worked on many systems, ones had the first, others had the perl version, some had both, all it did was confusion.